# Twitter API - check if account is suspended

Tags: php, api, twitter

For one of my tools I have a database with lots of twitter accounts.
Sometimes it happens, that account which are listed in the database are suspended by twitter.

I would like to know if there is a way to check if a account is suspended.

I'm using the php twitter api library by Abraham Williams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the [users lookup query](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) with the user ids you want to check.

The ones **left out** of the list will be the **suspended** ones.

That's the way I have accomplished it so far. Not sure if there's specific methods to do such.